# How can I use Perl's File::Find inside a Moose Object?

Tags: perl, moose

I'm building a Perl application that relies on Moose. One task the Moose object needs to accomplish is to use File::Find to populate an attribute with a list of files. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use find's `\&wanted` code reference in a way that will let me maintain access to a `$self` version of the Moose object.

So far, I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyMoose;

use Modern::Perl;
use Moose;
use File::Find;
use FindBin qw($Bin);

### Attribute to hold the file list
has "file_list" => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'ArrayRef',
    default => sub {[]}
);


### Method to populate the file list
sub update_file_list {

    my $self = shift;

    find(\&wanted, $Bin);

}


### File::Find wanted sub
sub wanted {

    ### This won't work, but shows what I'd like to do
    #   my $self = shift;
    #   ### Do some filtering
    #   push @{$self->file_list}, $File::Find::name;

}


1;


######################################################################
### Main package to test the object.

package main;

use Data::Dumper;

run_main() unless caller();

sub run_main {

    my $m = MyMoose->new();

    $m->update_file_list();

    print Dumper $m->file_list;

}
```

It runs, but obviously doesn't assemble a file list. That's the part I'm trying to figure out.

What's the proper way to use File::Find so that it will let you have access to the Moose object during processing?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you might want to take a look at [the `recurse` method in `Path::Class::Dir`](https://metacpan.org/module/Path%3A%3AClass%3A%3ADir), which can be used instead of `File::Find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have access to `$self` within `wanted` sub. You can use inline closure and `default` or `builder` to build the list.

**Edit:** updated code per updated question

```
has "file_list" => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'ArrayRef',
    default => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->_get_file_list();
    },
);

sub update_file_list {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->file_list($self->_get_file_list());
}

sub _get_file_list {
    my @files;
    find(sub { push @files, $File::Find::name }, $Bin);
    return \@files;
}
```

`_get_file_list` method returns arrayref of files found. It is used both in `default` and `update_file_list` method to populate the attribute.

Comment: In the original example, I shouldn't have put the call in BUILD. I actually need to be able to update the file list arbitrarily via it's own method. (I've updated the question example code to represent this.) So, default won't help here. I'll do some looking at builder to see how it behaves.

Comment: @AlanW.Smith - please see the update. Builder is no different from default actually, you just specify method by name, so you can benefit from overriding it in subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

As bvr notes, the subroutine reference passed to `find` doesn't need to be a named package method — a lexical [closure](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-a-closure%3F) will work just fine.  Thus, you can do this:

```
sub update_file_list {

    my $self = shift;

    my $wanted = sub {

        ### Do some filtering
        push @{$self->file_list}, $File::Find::name;

    };

    find($wanted, $Bin);    

}
```

The lexical variable `$self` declared in the outer function scope will be visible in the inner function.

In particular, every time the `update_file_list` method is called, a new `$self` and a new `$wanted` will be created (and bound together by the inner reference to `$self`), so that it's perfectly safe to call the method several times on different objects, even recursively if you want.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial an error, I also got the script to work by replacing the original version of 'update_file_list' with this:

```
sub update_file_list {

    my $self = shift;

    find( sub { wanted($self); }, $Bin );

}
```

That seems to work as well.